# Silly question regarding improper integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I was messing around with infinite sums and products inside of integrals and I came up with this integral:

$$
I(n) = A(n) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \biggl( \prod_{k=1}^{u}\frac{1}{x^{2}+k^{2}} \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
Where A(n) is:
$$
A(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^n
$$
All $n$ will cause $A(n)$ to completely blow up but this isn't a huge problem because of the integral running on the reals. Evaluating this integral is pretty easy with contour integration over a semicircle with a radius $R$ (as $R\to\infty$).The poles are contained on the imaginary axis and we can just use the residue theorem to find the value of the original integral, the integral is always equal to zero. After evaluating that we have this an limit to evaluate.

**Example:**

\begin{gather*}
I(1) = A(1)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \biggl(\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{2}+k^{2}} \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x, \\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \biggl( \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{2}+k^{2}} \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0, \\
I(1) = A(1) \cdot 0.
\end{gather*}

Substituting $m$ for $0$ gives us:

This is an indeterminate form $0\cdot\infty$ as $A(1)$ diverges off to infinity and $m\to0$.

$$ I(1) = \lim_{m\to0} A(1) \cdot m. $$

$A(1)$ approaches infinity in the limit and we can rewrite $m$ as $1/(1/m)$ so that we can use L'hopital's rule.

\begin{align*}
I(1)
&= \lim_{m\to0} \frac{A(1)}{\frac{1}{m}} \\
&= \lim_{m\to0} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} m} A(1) }{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} m} \frac{1}{m}} \\
&= \lim_{m\to0} \frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}m} (1+2+3+4+5+\cdots) }{-\frac{1}{m^{2}}} \\
&= \lim_{m\to0} \frac{0+0+0+\cdots}{-\frac{1}{m^{2}}} \\
&= -\lim_{m\to0} \frac{0}{\infty} = 0
\end{align*}

([WolframAlpha computation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iigQL.png)) The most suspicious part is the differentiation of $A(1)$ with respect to m, but WolframAlpha says otherwise.
I want to figure out what $n$ would make the integral $I(n)$ converge such that $I(n)$ is bounded between the interval $(0, \infty)$, for $n$ is a natural number. I have no idea where to start and I've tried many values of $n$, but all of them causes $I(n)$ to go to $0$, unless I(n) is just equal to $0$ for all $n$, which is enough for me to rest.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here. Your $I(n)$ is simply $\zeta(-n)$ multiplied by some constant (as the value of the improper integral). Also, $\zeta(-n)$ is *well-defined*, provided $\zeta(\cdot)$ stands for the Riemann zeta function (which is a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$). What you wrote in Example is even more perplexing and seems making no sense to me. You would really want to sanitize your question in a mathematical way. (Perhaps you may present the original computation that led to the expression $I(n)$.)

Comment: By the way, it seems to me that $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\biggl(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x^2+k^2}\biggr)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2 \cdot n!(n-1)!(2n-1)}. $$

Comment: what's the question here? you never asked a question.
and where did I(n) come from? did you just make it up?

Comment: Note that $I(n)$ is of the form $$\infty \cdot 0,$$ which is a quintessential example of **indeterminate**. Assuming that $I(n)$ is a consequence of certain limiting procedure, being an indeterminate signals that the behavior of the limit hinges on a delicate tug-of-war between the growth of whatever leading to $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^n=\infty$ and the decay of the one leading to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2+k^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=0$.

Comment: @phi-rate I(n) is simply made up and I just wanted to see what inputs of the function would lead to an output such that $0$<$I(n)$<$\infty$

Comment: @SangchulLee. Are you sure about the $2$ in the denominator ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, In hindsight, I guess I actually computed the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\ldots$ instead. Thank you for pointing out my mistake!